# Alpha vantage API "invalid api call" - Intraday and currency digital currency exchange rate

Tags: python, api, alpha-vantage

When I try to take intraday data for cryptocurrencies it returns `invalid api call`

When I change it to daily, the request works fine. ForeignExchange and TimeSeries are also working fine, only the exchange rate on cryptocurrencires and intraday.

Here is my code:

```
from alpha_vantage.cryptocurrencies import CryptoCurrencies

ts = CryptoCurrencies(key="my_key", output_format="pandas")
data= ts.get_digital_currency_exchange_rate(symbol='BTC',market='USD')
```

and here is the error i get:

```
ValueError: Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE.
```

Comment: Looks like issue with the api. Try raising an issue in thier github repo.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. Intraday support for cryptocurrencies is unavailable on the Alpha Vantage platform. If you go to the [documentation](https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/#digital-currency) you'll see it has daily, weekly, and monthly but not intraday.
2. To get the price of `BTC` in `USD` you have to use `ForeignExchange`.
   Here is your adjusted properly working code:

```py
from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange

ts = ForeignExchange(key="my_key", output_format="pandas")
data= ts.get_currency_exchange_rate(from_currency='BTC',to_currency='USD')
print(data)
```